# Сравнить изображения разного размера Python

Tags: python, img, сравнение

Необходимо вычислить из какого изображения .jpg получена миниатюра .jpg, которая обрезана и уменьшена в размерах.
Т.е. сравнить два .jpg разного размера и пропорций на которых изображено одно и тоже.

Как происходит|производится такое сравнение?
Есть ли готовые инструменты на Python для такого сравнения?
Дайте, пожалуйста, пример.

Comment: Слишком абстрактный вопрос, начните с чего-то попроще и поконкретнее. Возьмите прямо вот конкретные примеры несколько штук и начните с них.

Comment: Миниатюра предполагает вырезание произвольного прямоугольника или только вертикальной/горизонтальной полосы исходного изображения? Второй случай намного проще.

Comment: Миниатюра - произвольный кусок из исходного изображения. А вообще-то изображений много и всех я не видел.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример изображения и миниатюры.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html

Comment: Т. е. было какое-то изображение, из него вырезали произвольный кусок и ещё уменьшили до произвольного размера с сохранением пропорций. Потом по результату этого преобразования из кучи потенциально исходных изображений надо выбрать исходное? Или сопоставить n миниатюр и n исходных изображений? Есть вероятность, что второе проще, но это не точно. И очень помогло бы исключить масштабирование из преобразований.

Comment: Да из изображения взяли кусок т.е. обрезали оригинал и обрезанное изображение уменьшили в размерах, так что с масштабом работать придется разным. На счет пропорций я не уверен, может быть и изменены, но то, что в миниатюре не полное изображение это точно. Миниатюра стоит в анонсе статьи, в статье 10-20 картинок из одной из них и сделана миниатюра, надо вычислить ту картинку. Статей Много, все не смотрел так что лучше, считать, что где-то пропорции изменены.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ здесь:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d27/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html

```
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib as plt

def compare_img(img_name1:str='', img_name2:str=''):
    img1 = cv.imread(img_name1, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)        # queryImage         
    img2 = cv.imread(img_name2, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)        # trainImage

    sift = cv.SIFT_create()                                         
    
    # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
    kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
    kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
    
    # BFMatcher with default params
    bf = cv.BFMatcher()
    matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
    
    # Apply ratio test
    good = []
    for m,n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
            good.append([m])
    
    # cv.drawMatchesKnn expects list of lists as matches.
    fl = cv.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS
    img3 = cv.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, flags=fl)
    plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

Comment: При написании ответа, пожалуйста, не ограничивайтесь одних лишь только кодом. Постарайтесь прокомментировать свое решение и объяснить его суть словами. Спасибо!